# Remove Checkbox Outline in Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I wonder how do I remove the orange box encapsulating the checkbox. I couldn't find a way to remove it? It does appear when my mouse is clicking on that part.

[image]

**StyledGrid**

```
export const StyledDataGrid = styled(DataGridPro)(({ theme }) => ({
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.white,
  border: 0,
  "& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeader,  .MuiDataGrid-cell,  .MuiDataGrid-cellCheckbox":
    {
      border: 0,
      ":focus": {
        outline: "none",
      },
    },
  "& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeaders": {
    borderTopLeftRadius: "8px",
    borderTopRightRadius: "8px",
    backgroundColor: "#fbfbfc",
    textTransform: "uppercase",
    "& .MuiDataGrid-menuIcon": {
      display: "none",
    },
    "& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeaderTitle": {
      color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
    },
    "& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeader--sorted .MuiDataGrid-columnHeaderTitle": {
      color: theme.palette.text.primary,
    },
  },
  "& .MuiDataGrid-row, & .MuiDataGrid-cell": {
    maxHeight: "initial !important",
    minHeight: "initial !important",
  },
}));
```

**Component**

```
  <StyledDataGrid
    columns={supplierColumns}
    rows={rows}
    loading={rows.length === 0}
    disableSelectionOnClick
    checkboxSelection
    onSelectionModelChange={(ids) => setSelectedRowIds(ids)}
    pageSize={pageSize}
    onPageSizeChange={(newPageSize) => setPageSize(newPageSize)}
    rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 20]}
    pagination
  />
```

Comment: Hello, which checkbox you mean , could you provide a screenshot

Comment: @MidoDevi. Added a picture above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to add outline directly , or try pesudo focus-within selector

```
  export const StyledDataGrid = styled(DataGridPro)(({ theme }) => ({
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.white,
      border: 0,
      "& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeader,  .MuiDataGrid-cell,  .MuiDataGrid-cellCheckbox":
        {
          border: 0,
        outline: "none"
        },
    }));


  export const StyledDataGrid = styled(DataGridPro)(({ theme }) => ({
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.white,
      border: 0,
      "& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeader,  .MuiDataGrid-cell,  .MuiDataGrid-cellCheckbox":
        {
          border: 0,
          "& :focus-within": {
          outline: "none"
          }
        },
    }));
```

Comment: It still appears. I tried both

Comment: i did a try in developer tools and override the css rule outline to none , and it worked

Comment: try add this rule to css file and check 

.css-1t75zoz .MuiDataGrid-columnHeader:focus-within, 
.css-1t75zoz .MuiDataGrid-cell:focus-within {
    outline: none !important;
}